# Creating a table where UserPassword not equal to UserName, but the following code returning a error

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Credentials 
(
    UserName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UserPassword VARCHAR(20) 
        CONSTRAINT chk_constraint CHECK (UserPassword <> UserName) NOT NULL,
)
```

I get this error:

> Column check constraint for column 'UserPassword' references another column, table (Credentials).

Comment: You're doing this wrong. It's **NEVER** okay to store a password in plain text. The password should be stored as a salted hash value. When someone logs in, you have to also salt and hash the attempted password, and then _compare the hashes_, not the original passwords. This also means checking username vs password is meaningless at this level as a database constraint.

Comment: Considering that `UserPassword` will be a hashed and salted value, it will *never* equal Username anyway.

Comment: Also, 20 characters is too short as a password length limit. **IF** you're going to enforce a length limit on passwords (and you shouldn't), the absolute minimum according to [NIST](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/) is 64 characters.

Comment: I am not storing any password. I just wanted to know how can imake a constraint which should check one column value should not equal to another column in same table.

Comment: That sure looks like you're storing a password 

Comment: I am a student. just practicing sql server

Comment: Yup it CONSTRAINT but still its giving error

Comment: This, along with SQL injection issues, is one of those things that too important to do wrong even in student, practice, and proof of concept code.

Comment: *"I am not storing any password"* Clearly *not* when you declare a column with the definition `UserPassword VARCHAR(20)`; that must be the user's date of birth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining column level constraints,

In a column level constraint, you can only define constraint for specific column.

For your requirement, you should go for table level constraints, from this you can define constraint for multiple columns, like:

```
CREATE TABLE Credentials 
(
    UserName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UserPassword VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT chk_constraint CHECK (UserPassword <> UserName)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want to create an independent check constraint, so change it like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Credentials 
(
    UserName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UserPassword VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT chk_constraint CHECK (UserPassword <> UserName)
)
```